# How to name several fields of a table within the 'case' in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to use the "case" in MySQL, it works when I use the first block of code (naming only one field), while in the second block of code (naming several fields) I get an error; it seems that using "case" does not allow me to use "," to separate the names of the fields, is there another way to name several fields from my table within the "case"?

## first block

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE Load_data (NP VARCHAR(10), Type VARCHAR(10)) 
BEGIN
    SELECT CASE 
      WHEN Type="Apod" THEN APA
      WHEN Type="Pad" THEN APP
      WHEN Type="Mad" THEN APM
      END FROM ap_data WHERE N=NP;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

## second block

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE Load_data (NP VARCHAR(10), Type VARCHAR(10)) 
BEGIN
    SELECT CASE 
      WHEN Type="Apod" THEN APA,AMA,NomA,DNIA,Direc,Cu,Mul,NAlum
      WHEN Type="Pad" THEN APP,AMP,NomP,DNIP
      WHEN Type="Mad" THEN APM,AMM,NomM,DNIM
      END FROM ap_data WHERE N=NP;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

result when executing the second block

1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AMA,NomA,DNIA,Direc,Cu,Mul,NAlum WHEN Type="Pad" THEN APP,AMP,NomP,DNIP WH' at line 4

Comment: The predicate of a `CASE` expression (i.e. what follows `THEN` or `ELSE`) has to be a single scalar value, it can't be a list of values or columns.  If you can explain what you are trying to here, maybe someone can give you a workaround.

Comment: as the second code shows I want to return the records of several fields as the case may be and not of a single field

Comment: That doesn't make much sense.  Please show sample input and the output you expect here.

Comment: I solved it, I just put my entire list in parentheses, thanks for the interest